# sql get query to get any student records who have passed multiple certificates?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, database-design, relational-database

i have 3 mysql tables.

1. certificates (certificate id, certificate name)
2. students (student id, name)
3. student certificates (id, student id, certificate id, reg_date)

How can i construct a sql query to get any student records who have passed 20 certificates (base on 20 different certificate ids)?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM student_certificates
GROUP BY student_id
HAVING COUNT([DISTINCT] certificate_id) >= 20
```

Join `students` table if some columns from it needed (do not forget to expand GROUP BY expression accordingly).

Comment: thank you. it has solved part of my problem. so how can i filter or select these 20 certificates ids that i want to be include in the course rather than count from the lot?